# ratelimit using node-rate-limiter-flexible -- how to use consume method?

Tags: javascript, rate-limiting

Using node-rate-limiter-flexible for the first time

I'm using sveltekit +server.js
Trying to ratelimit the post to that route so :

```
import { RateLimiterMemory } from "rate-limiter-flexible";
const opts = {
      points: 6, // 6 points
      duration: 1, // Per second
    };

const rateLimiter = new RateLimiterMemory(opts);

export async function POST(requestEvent){
// some code that is irrelevant to my question to collect email from the user

let consumeit = await rateLimiter.consume(email, 2)



} //end of post function
```

Now when I console log consumeit, I get the following :

```
consumeit log :  {
  remainingPoints: 4,
  msBeforeNext: 1000,
  consumedPoints: 2,
  isFirstInDuration: true
}
```

What do I do from here? I need to use if/else to see if the route is limited or not to return something to my user, so how do I do

if(limited) {
return to user ("you clicked many times")
}else{
return to user ("thank you for using our service")
}

Do I use if (remainingPoints == 0) or use (isFirstInDuration == false)??
The doc api is not clear about the next step after you use consume method.

Anyone with experience using it and willing to help??

Comment: If you run into a limit because there are not enough points left, `consume` will throw an error (i.e. reject the returned promise), see [the documentation](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/API-methods#ratelimiterconsumekey-points--1-options--). So it's not `if`/`else`, but rather `try`/`catch` (or `.catch()`).